# How can I monitor GPU memory allocated by Tensorflow Serving

Tags: tensorflow, memory, tensorflow-serving

When I use `nvidia-smi` command I can see in the processes section how much memory is allocated by Tensorflow Serving. Is there a way to check how much is actually used by loaded models? How can I know if there is still some free memory to load the next model?

Comment: This is already been discussed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/1407) but there is no specific feature from tensorflow serving that will help you in doing this.